# Magento login admin page FATAL ERROR / WHITE SCREEN

Tags: admin, login, ce-1.9.0.1

My Magento login admin page has a FATAL ERROR / WHITE SCREEN

I've looked at the other questions which were similar but haven't been able to fix it. My site is at
**Problem:**

**Attempts to Fix:**

Another post said to:

> "In your app/etc/local.xml set disable_local_modules to true and check. If it loads fine then the issue is in one of your custom modules"*
>
> *Clear Cache*

I followed these instruction but the Admin login page is still a white screen.

**ERROR LOGS**

**/Var/Report:**

::::::::::::One of the files in /var/report there was an error:::::::::::::

Comment: from your index.php uncomment the line #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Set debugging mode on. Post that fatal error here

Comment: Check for PHP memory limit.

Comment: Check error logs and report back

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your answers! Can you please tell me which directory to check the errors? I am a bit lost.

Comment: FOUND THIS IN PUBLIC HTML ERROR_LOG[08-Jul-2014 20:29:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /home/statis91/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 104

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Appreciated. I recreated my site though =P

Comment: Try : ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in index.php
or increase memory to your php.ini regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I take a look at the line 104 your error logs are complaining about, I see the following

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
    return $this;
}
```

It looks like Magento's trying to grab a reference to the `menu` block, but it can't became some customization to your system has removed this menu, and then tried to call `setActive` on a non-object.

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$block  = $layout->getBlock('menu');
$block->setActive($menuPath);
```

So, your first question should be what removed this menu. Possibilities include

- A custom module
- Someone's hacked some core code
- Your admin layout XML files are somehow inaccesible to Magento, and the menu was never added

Based on the rest of your question, and the other errors you're seeing (a missing `mage_banners` table), it sounds like your best bet may be finding a Magento professional to help get your site repaired.  It seems like these issues may be the only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Hi Alan! I greatly appreciate your help.

Is the Menu you're referring to the frontend Catalog Menu? I use CustomMenu extension.

I am currently transferring most of the pages into a new install, copy and pasting content page by page. I believe this is the best option since I am not familiar with code. 

Thank you for the help and thorough answer!

Answer (score 7):

In my case, after updating a testshop installation from `1.7.0.2` to `1.9.1.0` (yes, I know: that's a huge update and trouble was expected), clearing the cache didn't help and as deactivating modules didn't show effects, I stopped there.

Then I found this entry at [ukbusinessforums.co.uk](http://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/1-8-1-1-9-1-fatal-error-in-action-php.327874/) and that did the trick for me. So I looked into `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/` and found, that after the update the `/etc/` directory was missing! So I downloaded the complete magento `1.9.1.0` suite and uploaded the `/adminhtml/default/default/` data and there the login was again! However, obviously, the CSS was missing - so I also uploaded the whole of the `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/` contents.

Now, everything is running smoothly again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue after upgrading magento version 1.8 to 1.9.

Magento upgrade unable to download the adminhtml design files.

So means you have to download the latest Magento version or in which Magento version you are upgrading.

After downloading copy all files from  to app/design/adminhtml and do this for skin adminhtml also.

May be this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found that during the upgrade process the files ending in .phtml under directory :var/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/preview were actually created as directories, so they were not able to be read properly. Remove them using rm -rf {name of directory}, and perform the upload for adminhtml as suggested by Vinay Sikarwar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the file system try deleting the cache folder in the var folder. Also look in var/log/exception to view the log files.

Try this go to

> app/etc/modules/< MODULE_NAME>.xml

and change

> < active >true< /active> to < active>false< /active>

for each module until you can get the admin page back. 
Remember to delete the cache folder in var/cache after each change. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I have manually deleted the cache before, but it didn't fix the issue! I do not see a /var/log/exception  |||| all i see here is /var/session, /var/report, /var/locks, /var/cache, /var/package,/var/backup, and a 1398366300_db.gz file, and some other files. Please tell me what else I can do or need to figure this out!

Comment: Hi, I found a error_log in main directory!

Comment: table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'statis91_mage2.mage_banners'

This is where I would begin looking it seems like you added an extension that didn't properly build out the tables.

Comment: This error occurred after the initial white page, I believe it was my attempt to fix on GoDaddy, I've reenabled that table on installatron . could you help guide me as to what the fatal error means?

Comment: after a quick google this seems like it pertains to [this](http://forum.aheadworks.com/base-table-or-view-not-found-t1933.html#p5618) but without knowing if there was an extension installed I'm just shooting in the dark. What happened prior to you getting this error?

Comment: Okay thank you for the help, however that post is regarding a post I believe? My issue is in regards to the Login page for Admin being completely blank (no login window) just a white page. Backtracking before the Fatal Error, I moved files from DEFAULT into RWD folder (Instructions from "IWD_All" or another extension guide), as well as installed and uninstalled on Magento Connect Manager several extensions.

Comment: Just to clarify the main issue of this post: Unable to Access Magento Admin Login! Need the blank /admin page to have Login Window!

Answer (score 0):

@Egregory Your answer solved my problem to make Magento 2.2.0 working.

After upgrading from Magento 2.1.0 to 2.2.0, my admin panel displays same error. After use your solution I am able to found my one of custom module stops working admin panel.

Thank you for your answer.