# White screen after updating Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, error, admin-panel

I have upgraded my magento to 1.9.2 and had 404 on Home page and white screen (blank page) on /admin. Home page I have fixed, but i have no idea what is the trouble with admin page.

I have cleared cache, checked logs... Nothing special. 
Who can help please?

Comment: check php logs, something is broken. 404 maybe your store code lost, or htaccess and rewrites not working

Comment: I already fixed 404 error. Now I try to understand why there is white page on /admin

Answer (score 1):

First enable Developer mode in your `.htaccess` file, add the following at the end of the file:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Next edit index.php and uncomment the line:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Line referenced:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/index.php#L73

Ensure `var/` is writeable by the webserver.

Enabling developer mode and display of errors you should now see the exception/error when attempting to login to the admin page vs a blank screen.

Comment: I wiil try it now, but dont think it could help me.. Developer mode also enabled.

Comment: oh, now I have press "return to admin" from downloader again and... 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 104

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28653/magento-login-admin-page-fatal-error-white-screen

Comment: Try re uploading all files located in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/` from a downloaded copy of the same version you installed via downloader (1.9.2.x) from magentocommerce.com

Comment: I must do it manually or I can go to downloader and reinstall "Mage_Core_Adminhtml"?

Comment: Both are options are worth trying, sometimes the downloader may not be the best option for upgrading. It is also has potential points of security exploits.

Comment: I re-uploaded files, I have login form now, I can enter login/password, but after it on "dashboard" page I get white screen again...